# Useful sites/services/resources/tools for learning Chinese

Tags: resources, websites

As [discussed on Meta](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/central-place-to-dump-resources), I think it would be great to have a collection of sites and resources for learning Chinese, so that we can all benefit from the sites, services and resources that other members find.

Please feel free to add any site or resource you think would be of value to all members of the site.

And also, to any of the mods, please turn this question into a community wiki. Thanks!

Comment: As I posted on [meta](http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/a/99/16), I think this question is too open-ended and chatty to fit on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: **For visitors**: If you're looking for resources visit the question [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-chinese).

Answer (score 4):

**[Singchinesesongs.com](http://singchinesesongs.com/)**

Sing Chinese Songs is a site where you can listen to Chinese music, hovering over the characters of the lyrics you can see the corresponding pinyin/meaning (as shown in the image).

[image: Sing Chinese Songs website]

Comment: That's awesome! Going to check it out now :-)

Comment: I'm now busy trying to learn 听妈妈的话 - man it's fast!

Comment: :S It's so fast, that's why it has 10/10 difficulty rating.

Answer (score 3):

**[Nciku.com](http://nciku.com)**

My favorite online dictionary service, that also has iPhone and Android apps available.

You can enter characters, pinyin, or even write them in, build vocab lists and more. You can also listen to different words/characters on the site to help improve your listening and pronunciation.

It's also free, and it's really useful for learning Mandarin.

[image: nciku.com]

Answer (score 3):

**[Jukuu.com](http://Jukuu.com)**

Jukuu is a site that can help put Chinese words into context for you. You enter the word you are looking for, and it will show you a bunch of different sentences using that word.

I find putting terms into context really helps with my learning process. Plus, it looks simple, and I like that.

[image: jukuu.com]

Answer (score 2):

**[CSLpod.com](http://CSLpod.com)**

CSLpod doesn't seem to be very well known, but they have a ton of great resources available for free, plus you can sign up to a subscription to get extra added value services, like lessons with teachers and so on.

I love their podcasts, plus the supporting materials that are provided, and find this to be a very valuable learning resource.

[image: cslpod.com]

Answer (score 2):

**[Skritter.com](http://skritter.com)**

Skritter is a helpful website for improving your writing abilities, and helping you to learn new vocab.

You can use a writing tablet or your mouse to enter characters from your wordlist, and get pretty feedback on how much study you have done, and how many characters you have memorised as you go on.

**It's $9.95 a month**, but worth it if you want to keep improving your writing skills.

[image: skritter.com]

Answer (score 2):

**[Zhongwen for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkmlkkjojmombglmlpbpapmhcaljjkde)**

Zhongwen for Chrome is a handy plugin that can help you to read Chinese text on websites, so you can read text that might otherwise be inaccessible to you.

You can also search words from a range of different online dictionaries, and even add them to your [Skritter](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/686/62) queue.

[image: Zhongwen for Chrome]

Answer (score 2):

**[CNTV's Learning Chinese section](http://english.cntv.cn/learnchinese/)**

CNTV, part of CCTV, broadcasts a range of different shows to help foreigners learning Chinese, along with show notes and other resources to improve your skills.

These shows are, for the most part, available free on the CNTV website from anywhere in the world, and a great way to practice your listening and reading skills.

[image: CNTV]

Answer (score 2):

[Living Language's Language Lab](http://livinglanguage.com/languagelab/distribution/2497)

This is a great free resource for beginner to intermediate learners. It's a free sampling of their paid course and includes a ton of vocabulary with audio and games testing grammar points as well as vocabulary.  There's material from beginner to "advanced" although the advanced material I would actually call intermediate. 
My favorite is the matching bubbles game to test character recognition. 
[image]